# Excel solver 5x5 sum game

Tags: excel, solver

My son found this math game app and I've been playing it. Essentially you have a 5x5 grid of numbers from 0-9, and then at the end of each column and row is a target sum. Every number in the grid can be turned on or off, and when the correct sum is achieved that row or column is highlighted. You can actually play on harder levels, but for an excel problem I decided to try 5x5 just to see if I could get solver to find the answer.

The way I designed this is as follows:

(a) Cells B2-F6 have the number values from the grid.
(b) Cells H2-L6 I put in all zeroes.
(c) Cells N2-S6 I put in as the product of B2 and H2, B3 and H3, etc.
(d) Cells N8-R8 are the sum of N2-N6, O2-O6, etc.
(e) Cells S2-S6 are the sums of N2-R2, N3-R3, etc.
(f) Cells N9-R9 are the target identified by the game.
(g) Cells N10-R10 are N9-N8, O9-O8, etc.
(h) Cells T2-T6 are the target identified by the game.
(i) Cells U2-U6 are T2-S2, T3-S3, etc.
(j) Cell W2 is =MAX(T2:T6,N9:R9)
(k) Cell T12 is =N10*W2^9+O10*W2^8+P10*W2^7+Q10*W2^6+R10*W2^5+U2*W2^4+U3*W2^3+U4*W2^2+U5*W2^1+U6*W2^0

In solver, I set the object of $T$12 to be value of 0, with constraints on variable cells $H$2:$L$6 as <=1, >=0, integer.

However, I can't seem to get solver to find me a solution. I solved it in the game first so I had a solution. When I put that in, solver will tell me it found a solution after changing nothing, or on the evolutionary one it will tell me it hasn't found anything better...of course not, I've already given you the solution. But if you change just one of the 5x5 grid to be wrong, it still can't find a solution. Is this just too complex for solver? It's weird to me that when it fails it has non-integer values in the cells. I keep wondering why it's trying non-integer values when I told it not to (and I did check to be sure my Ignore Integer Constraints box is unchecked). I understand that there are 2^25 different possibilities it should have to try, but there's an infinite number more (okay, maybe finite if it has a maximum number of decimals in the data type, but for all practical, non-quantum purposes, it's infinite) if it ignores my integer requirements. Maybe it's just not comfortable with a brute-force approach and is trying to head a particular direction and just keeps finding that unsatisfactory. I also recognize that my cell T12 formula may be too much for it to handle. It just won't let me have multiple targets so I was trying to come up with a way for it to guarantee no false positives (e.g., if you just add all the difference cells in N10-S10 and U2-U6, which should all be zero, you can actually get solutions where some of the columns are non-zero but add up to zero because of positives and negatives...and those are result cells, so I can't similarly constrain them, I think).

Anyhow, here's the number set:

2 9 3 2 3
9 9 8 4 1
2 6 5 2 6
3 1 6 8 7
6 8 3 6 9

Row totals = 13, 4, 7, 19, 32 from top to bottom
Column totals = 13, 18, 8, 20, 16

I'd give you the answer...but where's the fun in that?

Comment: By the way, I wrote what I'm sure is a REALLY  REALLY inefficient SQL script to solve this puzzle. It takes about 30 minutes to exhaust all the possibilities (or about 15 minutes on average if I let it exit out when it finds a solution, I would expect). Excel doesn't usually like to have Solver running that long. So I can see why they wouldn't like the brute force method. I still maintain that they shouldn't be using decimals if I told them not to, even if that means they more quickly arrive at the conclusion that there's no easy solution to be found.

Comment: Excel's solver allows variables to be some epsilon outside any integer value. I.e. you may see 4.00001 but you should not see 4.3.